# Firebase web sends 4 read requests when using get function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Right now, I'm trying to make sure that I use the minimum amount of requests.

I have been able to boil it down to two requests. However, weirdly enough, when I send one request for a document using the `.get` function, it ends up counting as 4 reads on my quota? I also see in the network tab that it sends 3-6 requests (2-3 GET, 2-3 POST) to the firestore server. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Here's my code for getting only 1 document:

```
        db.collection("images")
        .where("labelled", "==", false)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            window.alert("All images have been labelled!");
            setFinishedLabel(true);
          } else {
            history.push("/label/" + querySnapshot.docs[0].id);
          }
        });
```

And here are the requests:
[image]

And the basic url for the request:
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2F`...

Comment: Are you still having this behaviour?

Comment: Yeah, I am @rsalinas